# Convert a csv larger than RAM into parquet with Dask

Tags: python, bigdata, dask

I have approximately 60,000 small CSV files of varying sizes 1MB to several hundred MB that I would like to convert into a single Parquet file. The total size of all the CSVs is around 1.3 TB. This is larger than the memory of the server that I am using (678 GB available).

Since all the CSVs have same fields, I've concatenated them into a single large file. I tried to process this file with Dask:

`ddf = dd.read_csv("large.csv", blocksize="1G").to_parquet("large.pqt")`

My understanding was that the blocksize option would prevent dask running out of memory when the job was split over multiple workers.

What happens is that eventually Dask does run out of memory and I get a bunch of messages like:

`distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker`

Is my approach completely wrong or am I just missing an important detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to concatenate all of your files into one large file.  `dd.read_csv` is happy to accept a list of filenames, or a string with a `"*"` in it.

If you have text data in your CSV file, then loading it into pandas or dask dataframes can expand the amount of memory used considerably, so your 1GB chunks might be quite a bit bigger than you expect.  Do things work if you use a smaller chunk size?  You might want to consult this doc entry: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#avoid-very-large-partitions

In general I recommend using Dask's dashboard to watch the computation, and see what is taking up your memory.  This might help you find a good solution.  https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html

Comment: Thanks, I did try loading from a list of files, tried smaller and larger chunks too. I am also using the dashboard to monitor the process. What I noticed is that everything is OK until RAM assigned to a worker fills up. Then processes start to break down and restart. My understanding was that Dask would handle these situations automatically, i.e. chunks would be read in only until memory fills up. Then those data would be processed, released from the memory and new data would be read in.

Comment: @SteveOB How did you solve your problem in the end? I have a similar problem

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio, Iwhat I did in the end was I cut up files into smaller chunks that would fit in memory safely. So I used Dask just to help me parallelize the operations.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar problem. All workers ended up using more memory than expected. After pausing and restarting with the error: "distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker". I was inspired by the solution at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73770527/dask-compute-uses-twice-the-expected-memory) and now it's working for my,I have no more errors or warnings. I only call ".compute()" at the end, without keeping the result in a variable. As on the example below:

this is my dask code :

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster,Client
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":

    dask.config.set({"temporary-directory": "{0}{1}/temp".format(databaseDirPath,base)})
    
    # Parameters
    cluster = LocalCluster(
                    n_workers=8, 
                    threads_per_worker=1,
                    memory_limit='auto',
                    interface='lo'
                    )
    client = Client(cluster)
    
# Some code ...
```

the header of my .csv :

```
feat1;feat2;feat3;feat4;feat5;feat6;feat7;feat8;feat9;feat10;feat11;feat12;feat13;feat14;feat15;feat16;feat17;feat18;feat19;feat20;feat21;feat22;feat23;feat24;feat25;feat26;feat27;feat28;feat29;feat30;feat31;feat32;feat33;feat34;feat35;feat36;feat37;feat38;feat39;feat40;feat41;feat42;feat43;feat44;feat45;feat46;feat47;feat48;feat49;feat50;feat51;feat52;feat53;feat54;feat55;feat56;feat57;feat58;feat59;feat60;feat61;feat62;feat63;feat64;feat65;number jobs;level(obj Value);depth;nbPruned
```

Before :

```
df = dd.read_csv("{0}.csv/x00*".format(databasePath),sep=";",blocksize="1MB",dtype=np.float64)

    for index,job in enumerate(jobs):
        print("calculation in progress for job : {0}".format(job))
        df2 = df[df["number jobs"] == job].compute()
        for idx, var in enumerate(dfColum.columns):
            print("feature : {0} with {1} jobs".format(var,job))
            cpt, edges = np.histogram(df2[var],bins=bins)
            frq = cpt / cpt.sum()
            # use this for histogram ...
    df.to_parquet("{0}.parquet/".format(databasePath))
```

After, I even increased the size of the blocksize and took the whole database, i.e. 500GB for my csv file. Whereas before I only had a 10GB database and 1 MB blocksizes.

```
df = dd.read_csv("{0}.csv/*".format(databasePath),sep=";",blocksize="64MB",dtype=np.float64)

    for index,job in enumerate(jobs):
        print("calculation in progress for job : {0}".format(job))
        df2 = df[df["number jobs"] == job]
        for idx, var in enumerate(dfColum.columns):
            # with numpy
            cpt, edges = np.histogram(df2[var].compute(),bins=bins)
            frq = cpt / cpt.sum()
            # use this for histogram ...

    df.to_parquet("{0}.parquet/".format(databasePath))
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34250598)