# Dask compute uses twice the expected memory

Tags: python, dask

I'm trying to understand and optimize the memory usage of Dask. For this simple example, I create an array that I would expect would occupy ~1GB of memory. When I realize the data with `persist()` this is what I find. But with `compute()` I see the amount of memory double.

Is this correct? And if so, why?

```
import dask.array as da
import resource

mem0 = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
memory = lambda: (resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss - mem0) / 1024

data = da.random.random((1024, 1024, 128))  # ~1 GB, not yet realized
print(f"Memory used: {memory()} MB")
# Memory used: 0.49609375 MB

data.persist()
print(f"Memory used: {memory()} MB")
# Memory used: 1023.49609375 MB

# Using .compute() instead of .persist()
# Memory used: 2047.5 MB
```

NB: I did not run `persist` and `compute` in the same script. I actually changed the code and ran again, to have a fair comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [`dask.Array.compute()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.Array.compute.html#dask.array.Array.compute), dask completes the task on the remote worker(s), then serializes the object, passes it back to the main thread, and then deserializes it. Therefore, there is likely to be one copy of the data on the workers, a copy being passed around as a string, and the version recreated on the main thread. Peak memory usage was likely more than 2x; at any given point the remote and partial local versions are in memory, plus copies of chunks in transit.

See the dask.distributed docs on [managing memory](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/memory.html#clearing-data). In the section on clearing data:

> We remove data from distributed RAM by removing the collection from our local process. Remote data is removed once all Futures pointing to that data are removed from all client machines.
>
> ```py
> del df  # Deleting local data often deletes remote data
> ```
>
> If this is the only copy then this will likely trigger the cluster to delete the data as well.
>
> However, if we have multiple copies or other collections based on this one, then we’ll have to delete them all.
>
> ```py
> df2 = df[df.x < 10]
> del df  # would not delete data, because df2 still tracks the futures
> ```

In your example, you never delete the reference to the remote object, meaning it must still be held on the remote cluster:

```py
# brings the data to the local thread while keeping the remote reference
data.compute()
```

If instead you overwrote the remote reference, the copy on your workers could at least be dropped once the call to `compute()` was finished:

```py
# drops the remote reference after bringing the data locally
data = data.compute()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helps a lot! I'm still struggling to understand how this applies to a single (local) machine with the default multithreading scheduler, though. As far as I understand, the worker(s) and the main thread share the same memory in this case, no? So, intuitively, there is no need to copy. Should I just avoid calling `compute()` in this situation?

Comment: Hmm - for the threaded scheduler on a local machine - that’s a good question. I’m actually much more familiar with the distributed scheduler on a cluster. This might be a good question for the dask discourse forum. Let us know if you find out something different to what I have here! You’ve got me curious :)